# how to transpose object of array in single object using DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How to transpose object of array in DataWeave to get a single JSON Object?
For example , I want to get output like

```
{
  "date": "20201124",
  "number": "NF006002CC21140000"
}
```

from below input

```
[
  {
    "name": "date",
    "value": "20201124",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "number",
    "value": "NF006002CC21140000",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` operation for this by defining the accumulator as an `Object`

```
payload reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> 
    {
        (accumulator),
        (item.name): item.value
    }
)
```

Here as the keys of the JSON is dynamically generated, you have to wrap the key expression in parentheses like `(item.name): item.value`.